# A Reformed Riley

Tags: riddle, word, affix-riddle

> Our prefix closes you in its arms
>   our infix is transmitting warmth
>   our suffix leaves no stone unturned
>   and yet our whole was deadly spurned.
>
> Forever in our minds is burned:
>   Barthélemy
>   We pray you've learned:
>   Who are we?

Comment: Just a fast one that came to mind. Not as polished as usual. Hope you still like it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are the

> Huguenots

Our prefix closes you in its arms

> HUG

our infix is transmitting warmth

> ENO is Eagle's Nest Outfitters who sell a variety of gear designed to keep you warm when camping

our suffix leaves no stone unturned

> STONE reversed (turned) is ENOTS (thanks to M Oehm for catching this)

and yet our whole was deadly spurned.

> The Huguenots were rejected by the Catholic majority of France

Forever in our minds is burned:
 Barthélemy

> The Massacre de la Saint-Barthelemy (St. Bartholomew's Day Massacre) in 1572 was a targeted group of assassinations and a wave of Catholic mob violence, directed against the Huguenots (Wikipedia)

Title Clue

> The Huguenots were part of the Protestant Reformation (REFORMED Riley)

Some of my answers are stretches, but the overall word fits well.

Comment: Very good! I think you should _literally_ turn the stone.

Comment: @M Oehm.  Good catch - I'll edit the better explanation in now.

Comment: @Pugmonkey. Yes, that's the answer I was looking for. You describe prefix,  suffix and title exactly as I meant them. There is only a problem with the infix. Your suggested infix together with prefix and suffix does not cover the complete word. - I admit that my take on the infix is probably the weakest of the three and might be quite obscure, depending on the focus of your educational background. So as a hint: Prefix, Infix and Suffix do not overlap. - I will mark this as the solution soon, but I'll keep the question open for a moment longer in case someone wants to tackle the infix.

Comment: @Karsten Köpnick.  I didn't feel good about my guess for infix, but I didn't see anything better.  Your hint that they are non-overlapping makes it obvious what the infix is, but I still can't make sense of the clue. Unless it is rot13(henavhz) which could transmit warmth, I suppose.

Comment: @Pugmonkey. Not what I had in mind, but I actually didn't think of that one, and i should have. I like it. And it's a lot closer to where I came from. I would not call this transmitting, rather emitting warmth in that case, but it fits well enough that I probably should stop nitpicking and accept this as alternative. - Another guess anyone? Otherwise it's solved for good.

Comment: I wouldn't have gotten the overall riddle, but just for completeness - rot13(svyz pbrssvpvrag)

Comment: Thanks @puzzle-guesser. That was the one I had in mind. Also known as rot13(urng genafsre pbrssvpvrag). Hope that was not too obscure.

Comment: @Karsten Köpnick.  Not too obscure - its just been a looooooong time since I took thermodynamics ...